# CodenameOne API, how to customise Local Notification text

Tags: codenameone

I think i've found a blocker in my app development that i hope you can help me out with please.I am using a CN1 Local Notification and i want them to be triggered at an interval at a particular time. The LocalNotification sample project works but please can you answer this. How can i code it so that each local notification text n.setAlertTitle() is customised\different each day, from reading from a List? All the examples i read have static text. 
I had thought of not making it repeat but initiating a new notification upon the user clicking previous one, but this would have the problem that if the user ignores the notification then no more would be sent, so i abandoned that approach.
Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is not to issue a recurring notification and instead register several separate notifications. You will need to store and manage the notification ID's so you can cancel and replace them.

In order to change the text dynamically your app needs to run and the basic idea of the notification is that it occurs while your app isn't running so it must be static.

Comment: That is what i have done and early testing shows it works. I took the tack that i would only create up to 7 daily notification requests-user would receive 1 for each day for the forward 7 days. When they went into the app then it would replenish any future missing requests. This would cater for them not going into the app for a few days. If the user hadn't gone in for a week then the notifications would run out, which i assumed was fine as the user isn't active enough. I used Storage for storing my last notificationId and lastDateSent values so they wouldn't be lost if the device was rebooted.